# my public IP point to the router settings instead of my website

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding

I am trying to host a website on my laptop using IIS v8
when I enter the hostname that points to my public IP it sends me to my router configurations page instead of my website even though I forward port 80 that I am using my router model is ZXV10 W300

In my search I found something about Internet/WAN-facing management interface or something like that, and that the configuration page uses this port so I need somehow to give it a different port to use but couldn't find it

Comment: You might also need to forward port 443 if HTTPS is used. There may be other ports that IIS uses for certain services but 80 (and these days, 443) is the minimum ports you should forward

Comment: Turn off Internet support for the router page - exposing it to the world is a very bad idea.

Comment: not using HTTPS for now but did forward port 443 to test it later 
I don't know how to Turn off Internet support for the router page, tried looking for it in the manual but with no luck

Comment: It's usually listed as **remote management/administration** in The form of a checkbox, radio button, or drop down. It's pretty rare to not be able to turn it off, as it's a pretty big security concern to have it open to the wild.

Comment: Where are you when you enter this address… inside or outside the network?

Comment: all testing is from inside the network trying to make it work from inside then test from outside



I think this option isn't available in this router I tried using a different port (81) for the website but that didn't work with the public IP

Comment: You need to test from outside. You will have great difficulty persuading it to route out then back again. Test from a local Starbuck's or over your mobile phone data plan. From outside. you should never see your router's config page. If you do, you need to change it.